# Rank of a matrix and graph connectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrix-rank, network, graph-connectivity

I have an homework where I need to investigate how the rank of a matrix relates to the connectivity of the associated graph. I have run some simulations and the claim below seems to hold,  but I have no clue how to show it. Could you help?

**MATRIX**

Consider a matrix $A$ structured as follows
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
A_1\\
A_2\\
\vdots\\
A_N
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where, for each $n\in \{1,...,N\}$, $A_n$ is a $T_n\times (NK+KJ)$ matrix.

Consider some numbers $\{k_{nt}\}_{n=1,...,N, t=1,...,T_n}$ where each $k_{nt}\in \{1,...,K\}$.

Consider some numbers $\{j_{nt}\}_{n=1,...,N, t=1,...,T_n}$ where each $j_{nt}\in \{1,...,J\}$.

For each $n\in \{1,...,N\}$, every $t$-th row of the matrix $A_n$ is structured as follows:

- The $\Big((n-1)K+k_{nt}\Big)$-th element is equal to $1$.
- The $\Big(KN+(j_{nt}-1)K+k_{nt}\Big)$-th element is equal to some scalar $\delta_{nt}>0$.
- All the other elements equal to zero.

Further, the matrix $A$ contains no zero columns and $\sum_{t=1}^{N} T_n \geq (NK+KJ)$.

---

**GRAPH**

Draw a a bipartite graph as follows:

- In one side (hereafter, side 1), we list all the pairs $\{j,k\}$ from $\{1,...,J\}\times \{1,...,K\}$.
- In the other side (hereafter, side 2), we list all the indices $n$ from $\{1,...,N\}$.
- We draw an edge from pair $\{j,k\}$ to index $n$ if there is $t\in \{1,...,T_n\}$ such that $j_{nt}=j$ and $k_{nt}=k$.

---

**Question:** I want to show that a necessary condition for the matrix $A$ to have full column rank is that in the graph:

- every pair $\{j,k\}$ in side 1 should be (indirectly) connected to at least another pair $\{j',k'\}$ in side 1.
- every index $n$ in side 2 should be (indirectly) connected to at least another index $n'$ in side 2.

Comment: You have essentially posted this same question twice. Is there a reason why you cannot combine these to a single question and delete the duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4023347/how-to-show-that-a-matrix-is-not-full-rank-using-the-linear-independence-definit

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The two questions are not equivalent. The question you have linked is about necessity and sufficiency for full rank when $N=J=1$. This question is about whether connectivity of the graph is necessary for full rank, for any $J,N$. I thought it was helpful to divide them into two separate questions, in order to simplify.

Comment: Can you send me the simulations? I'm having trouble visualising the matrix and the function together, because the matrix is too large to try to construct even for a simple function.