# How to show that a matrix is not full rank using the linear independence definition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

I want to show that the matrix $A$ defined below is **NOT** full column rank. I have a proof but it does not look complete to me. Could you help to fix it?

Consider a matrix $A$ structured as follows
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
A_1\\
A_2\\
\vdots\\
A_N
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where, for each $n\in \{1,...,N\}$, $A_n$ is a $T_n\times (NK+KJ)$ matrix.

Consider some numbers $\{k_{nt}\}_{n=1,...,N, t=1,...,T_n}$ where each $k_{nt}\in \{1,...,K\}$.

Consider some numbers $\{j_{nt}\}_{n=1,...,N, t=1,...,T_n}$ where each $j_{nt}\in \{1,...,J\}$.

For each $n\in \{1,...,N\}$, every $t$-th row of the matrix $A_n$ is structured as follows:

- The $\Big((n-1)K+k_{nt}\Big)$-th element is equal to $1$.
- The $\Big(KN+(j_{nt}-1)K+k_{nt}\Big)$-th element is equal to some scalar $\delta_{n}>0$. **Note here that $\delta_n$ is equal across rows of $A_n$.**
- All the other elements equal to zero.

Further, the matrix $A$ contains no zero columns and $\sum_{t=1}^{N} T_n \geq (NK+KJ)$.

---

**MY PROOF:**

Given the structure of $A$, we have that $A$ has full column rank if and only if the following system admits as unique solution $x=0_{(NK+KJ)\times 1}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 x_{a_{nt}} + \delta_{n} x_{b_{nt}}=0\hspace{1cm} \quad & \text{$a_{nt}\equiv (n-1)K+k_{nt}$, } \text{$b_{nt}\equiv NK+(j_{nt}-1)K+k_{nt}$,}\\
& \text{for each $t\in \{1,...,T_n\}$ and $n\in \{1,...,N\}$}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Observe that $x_{a_{nt}}$ appears twice in the system if and only if there is $\tau\neq t\in \{1,...,T_n\}$ such that $k_{n\tau}=k_{nt}$. In this case,  the system contains the equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &x_{a_{nt}} + \delta_{n} x_{b_{nt}}=0,\\
&x_{a_{nt}} + \delta_{n} x_{c_{n\tau}}=0,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
which admits any solution if $b_{nt}=c_{n\tau}$, or admits any solution such that $x_{b_{nt}}=x_{c_{n\tau}}$ if $b_{nt}\neq c_{n\tau}$.

Similarly, $x_{b_{nt}}$ appears twice in the system either because we are in the case above, or because there exists $n'\neq n \in \{1,...,N\}$ and $\tau\in \{1,...,T_{n'}\}$ with $k_{n'\tau}=k_{nt}$ and $j_{n'\tau}=j_{nt}$. In the last case, the system contains the equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &x_{a_{nt}} + \delta_{n} x_{b_{nt}}=0,\\
& x_{d_{n'\tau}} + \delta_{n'} x_{b_{nt}}=0,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
which admits any solution such that $x_{a_{nt}}=x_{d_{n'\tau}}$ if $\delta_n=\delta_{n'}$, or admits any solution such that $\frac{x_{a_{nt}}}{\delta_{n}}=\frac{x_{d_{n'\tau}}}{\delta_{n'}}$ if $\delta_n\neq  \delta_{n'}$.

Therefore, $x=0_{(NK+KJ)\times 1}$ cannot be the unique solution of the system. **I'm not sure I can conclude that because I have only looked at local sub-systems.**

Comment: For my personal interest : I think you recently asked a question about another matrix and wished to know if it was full rank or not. May I ask what these matrices are, in the broader context of your study? It seems that you should keep a textbook on Matrix Analysis handy. Have you considered any books on Matrix Analysis which may contain the keys to unlocking some of the questions you have asked here? Finally, of utmost help is an example : if you can come up with an example of a matrix like $A$, I am sure that you will get excellent attention, not that you are short of it now.+1